# Upload from specific folder only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my working **upload button** that is used to browse an image *from any folder* and then decode the image

Here is my code in js:

```
var imghtml='<div id="qrfile"><canvas id="out-canvas" width="320" height="240"></canvas>'+
    '<div id="imghelp">Select a QR'+
    '<br>or drag & drop here'+
    '<input type="file" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)"/>'+
    '</div>'+
'</div>';
```

And here is the function handleFiles:

```
function handleFiles(f)
{
    var o=[];

    for(var i =0;i<f.length;i++)
    {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
            canx.clearRect(0, 0, bCanvas.width, bCanvas.height);

            qrcode.decode(e.target.result);
        };
        })(f[i]);
        reader.readAsDataURL(f[i]); 
    }
}
```

I dont want user to browse all folder but rather one specific folder, defined by me, where all image will be store ( am currently using localhost but will move it to web server afterward). anyone can help please?

Comment: You `cant set any file/folder` location for `input type="file"` due to security reasons

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done because of security reasons. You have no option to do this. If you would be able to, users might accidentally upload files that are not meant to be uploaded (bank account information).

You might want to consider persuing the possibility to upload multple files in one upload prompt dialog. That way you at least don't have to do every file individually ;)

Comment: Nopes, let me clarify something... It's not really an upload button, it more like a browse button where you look for qr image from your pc and then upload it for decoding. The upload is not saved in the server. Now what i want to do is to allow the user to browse image only from a specific source (on my defined folder)

Comment: @user3342746: You still can't do it.  Browsers don't let you.  What if you decided to be evil and force users to upload files from `C:\Windows`.  It's a security feature, you cannot change/access the directory tree on the user's system.

Comment: assume it will be on a web server folder, e.g (fictious url): http:be57.com/files where all image are stored, now is there a solution? or can u propose me an alternative?